# Query to check if a value exists in a set of columns

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy

For my setup, I have to store the results of some games that people play using my server. At the end of a specific game, I have to store that the game is over, which team won (team 1 or team 2) and the players for each team. Let us suppose that a player is simply an integer (which is its identification id). So, for example, at same point I could have to store that the game number 3124 ended, that the team 1 won that game and that the first team was made by players (234213, 215345, 15661, 673423, ...) and that the team 2 was made by the players (21352, 756756, 2834568, ...). The problem is that the number of the players is variable, with a maximum of 32 per team. My first idea was to create a Postgres database using SQLAlchemy, but then I have to create a table with 64 columns (team1_player1, team1_player2, team1_player3, ...) and I have not found a way to create this table in an automated way. Moreover, a tipical query that I have to submit is "how many games has this player won?" and find the answer to this question is a nightmare that requires 64 queries.

Is this problem better handled by NoSQL databases? Is my current solution at least acceptable? Is there a way to check how many times a specific player id appears in all the columns of the form teamX_playerXX?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily model this in SQLAlchemy using ManyToMany relations
Have a look at their documentation [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many)
Try this in your application

```
team_player_table = Table(
    'team_player', Base.metadata,
    Column('team_id', Integer, ForeignKey('team.id')),
    Column('player_id', Integer, ForeignKey('player.id'))
)


class Team(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'team'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    players = relationship('Player', secondary=association_table)


class Player(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'player'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


game_team_table = Table(
    'game_team', Base.metadata,
    Column('game_id', Integer, ForeignKey('game.id')),
    Column('team_id', Integer, ForeignKey('team.id'))
)


class Game(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'game'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    teams = relationship('Team', secondary=association_table)
    winner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('team.id'))
    winner = relationship('Team', backref=backref('won_games'))
```

This way you can query how many games a player has won.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly what I needed!

Comment: @SteP glad to help. Could you please accept the answer?